# Создание задачи в YouTrack из почты. Автоматическое значение поля Assignee

Tags: youtrack

У меня создан проект, где все задачи создаются путём отправки письма на ящик ютрека. В копии письма указывается исполнитель задачи. Так вот, как сделать так, чтобы поле Assignee принимало значение адресата копии письма?
Assignee ${cc} в правиле mailbox проекта не помогает. 
Пожалуйста, помогите

Answer (score 0):

Так происходит потому, что placeholder ${cc} выставляет мейл-адрес, а не конкретного пользователя.

Самое простое в этом случае - написать workflow, который в момент репорта задачи будет проставлять Assignee в соответствии с reporter'ом задачи.
В таком случае нужно будет правильно настроить выбор репортера в правиле mailbox integration.

Comment: Liubov Dievskaia, огромное спасибо за ответ :) но этот метод не совсем подходит, т.к. в правиле mailbox integration  reporter'ом выставляется отправитель письма, а мне необходим адресат копии письма.